# show AVG value in table

Tags: ssrs-2008, reportbuilder3.0

I have table in report builder which I grouped by value (first column)
in second column I want it to show only the AVG of each group data.
how can I do it?

[table screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhVaI.png)

Answer (score 0):

With the following expression. Important is, that you add the scope:

```
=Avg(Fields!YourField.Value, "YourGroupName")
```